# Pipe buffer image data into Uint8ClampedArray format in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, image-processing

I'm trying to pipe image data into a function that I have been successfully using in the browser.

The code in the browser is as follows:

```
var myImageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, width, height);
var gray = tracking.Image.grayscale(myImageData.data, width, height);
```

That works just fine and from what I understand appears to be generating an `ImageData` object from an image in the `canvas`.

The `.data` property of the `ImageData` object appears to be a `Uint8ClampedArray` that reads `[r1, g1, b1, a1, r2, g2, b2, a2.....]` Looking at the pattern, every fourth number is `255` which makes sense as none of the image is transparent at all.

I am trying to get this to work in Node.js in a similar fashion, except I'm getting my image data from a buffer generated by https://github.com/lovell/sharp:

```
sharp(body)
    .resize(newWidth, newHeight)
    .raw()
    .toBuffer(function (err, buffer, info) {
        var gray = tracking.Image.grayscale(buffer, newWidth, newHeight);
    });
```

The problem is, this clearly doesn't work.

I can't pass the buffer directly to the function. I've tried a ton of things and the only process that actually shows me an array is `buffer.toJSON().data`. Looking at that, the numbers are all <= 255, however I can't see any *every fourth number is 255* pattern which indicates something is wrong.

---

**My question is:**

How can I get an `Uint8ClampedArray` with the proper `[r1, g1, b1, a1, r2, g2, b2, a2.....]` formatting from the image buffer in Node.js that I can then pass to my function?

---

Sharp provides other buffer encoding methods like `.png()` or `.jpeg()` but neither of those have worked for me and I would assume that the `.raw()` function which I am currently using would give me what I want.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The input is missing alpha channel. I think the easiest thing is just to join a new channel like this:

```
sharp(body)
  .resize(newWidth, newHeight)
  .joinChannel(Buffer.alloc(newWidth * newHeight, 255), {
    raw: {
      width: newWidth,
      height: newHeight,
      channels: 1
    }
  })
  .raw()
  .toBuffer(function (err, buffer, info) {
    var gray = tracking.Image.grayscale(buffer, newWidth, newHeight);
  });
```